# How to show support case number on saved search of bills that is related to the PO that is related to the bill. (2 levels of related records)?

Tags: netsuite

We use Support Cases as Work Orders for our property management.

The case is connected to a PO.

When the PO is received and a bill is created I want a saved search of the unapproved bills to also show the related case. The case however is related to the PO and not the bill, but the PO is related to the bill.

I can do a saved search of POs that shows the case number that it is related to, and I can show the PO that a bill is related to on a saved search of bills, but I'm stumped how to go one level deeper on a bill saved search.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately NetSuite currently does not support two levels of joins. In order to show both a bill and a case related to a PO, you would need to do your search on POs instead of bills.

Comment: Thanks, this is a perfectly acceptable solution, Thanks for your assistance.